# Oracle use of Max on date column with order by "skips" results

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query "skips" rows that fall within the specified range.

```
Select Apples.*, Chiquita.color, Bananas.Time   
from Apples,  
(Select Carrot.name, Apple.type, Banana.color, MAX(Carrot.Time) as CarrotTime  
 From Apples Apple, Bananas Banana, Carrots Carrot  
where  Apple.color = Banana.color  
group by Carrot.name, Apple.type, Banana.color) Chiquita  
where rownum <= 20  
order by CarrotTime DESC;
```

Now if I modify rownum to say `40` I get results that are interspersed between the date ranges.  To clarify:
rownum = 20 returns dates like so:

```
 1,12-Jun-11  
  ...  
  20, 22-May-11
```

rownum = 40 returns information like so:

```
  1, 12-Jun-11
  ...
  20, 29-May-11  //Notice that this row 20 does not equal the information from the other row 20
  ...  
  40, 22-May-11
```

Comment: Your naming scheme is *extremely* fruity.

Comment: I see what you did there

Comment: There is a table `Carrots` in the subquery that is not joined to the others. This will result in a CROSS PRODUCT. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes duplicate removal is done in the back

Comment: But it skews the results and affects your ordering.

Comment: There is also a `Bananas.Time` in the SELECT list which is not defined in the query. As it is, this query would not run.

Comment: I suggest you try using Analytic functions instead of `rownum`: http://www.orafaq.com/node/55

Comment: I'd also suggest using ANSI JOIN syntax - it's much clearer.

Answer (score 6):

```
where rownum <= 20   
order by CarrotTime DESC;
```

Oracle processes the where clause prior to the order by. So your query selects the first 20 rows that it happens to get to and then applies the order of CarrotTime. This is generally fixed by moving the order by into a sub query, like StevieG suggests. However the order of the inner query is not guaranteed when the results are joined.

Try yet another inner query (untested):

```
Select *
from (Select Apples.*, Chiquita.color, Bananas.Time
    from Apples,
    (Select Carrot.name, Apple.type, Banana.color, MAX(Carrot.Time) as CarrotTime
        From Apples Apple, Bananas Banana, Carrots Carrot
        where  Apple.color = Banana.color
        group by Carrot.name, Apple.type, Banana.color) Chiquita
    order by CarrotTime DESC)
where rownum <= 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Your comparision wil not be accurate unless

```
a) You view the complete result set from both Queries or

b) You are sure you have only one record in the result set for a given ID..
```

For your example, It is possible that when you have two records like..

```
20, 22-May-11
20, 29-May-11
```

after the join and when you add rownum < 20, you are seeing the first row, and rownum < 40, you are seeing the second row.

If you want the result sets to be consistent, you might have to order the results before you get the top 20 or 40 rows.

Something like..

```
select * from (
Select Apples.*, Chiquita.color, Bananas.Time   
from Apples,  
(
  Select Carrot.name, Apple.type, Banana.color, MAX(Carrot.Time) as CarrotTime  
  From Apples Apple, Bananas Banana, Carrots Carrot  
  where  Apple.color = Banana.color  
  group by Carrot.name, Apple.type, Banana.color
  order by MAX(Carrot.Time)
) Chiquita  
order by CarrotTime DESC
)
where rownum < 20 ---or rownum < 40
```

Also, your Query seems to be having cartesian joins,

1) inside the Chiquita  (3 tables and only one join)

2) between Apples and Chiquita

This is usually a mistake, so You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing its because the rows in your subquery are not ordered. Try this:

```
Select Apples.*, Chiquita.color, Bananas.Time   
from Apples,  
(
  Select Carrot.name, Apple.type, Banana.color, Carrot.CarrotTime
  From Apples Apple, Bananas Banana, 
       ( 
         select name, MAX(Time) as CarrotTime 
         from Carrots 
         group by name
         order by MAX(Time), name
       ) Carrot
  where  Apple.color = Banana.color  
  group by Carrot.name, Apple.type, Banana.color
  order by Carrot.CarrotTime, Carrot.name)
) Chiquita  
where rownum <= 20  
order by CarrotTime DESC;
```

Comment: I'm just wondering if the database guarantees the same order coming back from your subquery given that it produces a cartesian product. Can you try that (i.e. run the subquery a few times and confirm the results are always in the same order)?

Comment: they in fact are not.  Which is becoming quite the issue